# How many first-time questions are asked on Stack Overflow each day?

Tags: support, new-users, statistics

How many first-time questions are asked on Stack Overflow each day?

Comment: Nobody knows how often an SO user creates a new account to ask the next question.  Ask about accounts instead of users and you'll get an answer, but that doesn't have anything to do with "first-time".  I did get a whiff of the company clamping down on duplicate account email addresses lately, but they don't clamp down the sites that let you create one for 24 hours.

Comment: Tricky to answer this from outside, as SEDE doesn't include deleted questions, and a **huge** number of accounts' first-time questions are presumably deleted. I don't think [site analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics) (25k+ link) lets us filter like that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder SEDE does have PostsWithDeleted but unfortunately that table is sanitized for deleted posts causing it the owneruserid column (among many others) to be null.

Comment: @rene - Thanks (is that newish?). It makes sense to redact that data, but it's too bad.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder newish as in a little bit over [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/158100) ;)

Comment: @rene - Thanks. I meant the feature of having any information on deleted posts. Looks like the feature's about three years old.

Comment: I tried to make a joke @T.J.Crowder but this one obviously felt flat. All these *bad* jokes bring me a step closer to my expulsion....

Comment: the most accurate answer would be how many new accounts are created each day that ask only one question ever!

Comment: I see 6 questions every minute.

Comment: Nice question for a change, it even repeats the title in body and it's all right!

Comment: @brasofilo Lol best question in SO ever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest answer is that, considering user accounts asking their initial question, Stack Overflow receives:

- Between 1700-2100 per day on weekdays (with some extremes above/below that)
- Between 850-1100 per day on weekends

There's some seasonal variation, particularly around the Christmas and New Year's celebrations, likely due to vacations.

The graph of the last year (August 2017 - July 2018) looks like this:

[image: Total first questions asked by a user over the course of the year]

This *includes*:

- Deleted questions that were deleted at any point after being posted, whether the same day or months later and for all reasons - including:

  - [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)-ed
  - manually deleted (by users/mods)
  - spam
  - self-deleted (by poster)
- Questions from now-deleted users sorted by username at time of deletion<sup>†</sup> - including:

  - mod deleted/destroyed accounts
  - self-deleted accounts

The huge asterisk I have to put on this is that users often use this site in strange and beautiful ways.

- Some users ask questions and delete them immediately after getting an answer.
- Some users use a new account for every question they ask (or a good number of them) - either deleting their account entirely or just abandoning it.
- Some users have various socks that they use legitimately (rather than for sockpuppet voting).

All of these impact how this data can be looked at but likely represent a small number of total posts.

---

<sup>†</sup> Note the caveat that because SO does not enforce unique usernames, including questions from now-deleted users is prone to error but inclusion of these deleted users accounts for a very tiny fraction of questions - about 10-20 questions per day.